# Page request not being applied to results

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I've been trying to add in sorting for a particular endpoint and I've been able to allow the url to specify which columns needs to be sorted. However despite showing the the result body as the parameters are showing, it doesn't seem to be applying to actual json result. Effectively what is happening is that, while when accessing the endpoint does show the page, size, direction and which column I have selected to be. It doesn't seem to be applying it to my results. Am I missing something?

```
    List<Example> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Page<Domain> page;

    List<Domain> domainList = page.getContent();
    for (Domain domain: domainList ) {
        result.add(convert(domain));
    }

    pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.ASC, columnOrder);

    return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
```

Comment: PageRequest should be used to call a SpringData Repository to get sorted/paged results. Creating a PageImpl by yourself won't filter/sort anything. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-

Answer (score 0):

This code is implementation of Pagination using spring JPA.

```
final PageRequest page1 = new PageRequest(
  0, 20, Direction.ASC, "lastName", "salary"
);

final PageRequest page2 = new PageRequest(
  0, 20, new Sort(
    new Order(Direction.ASC, "lastName"), 
    new Order(Direction.DESC, "salary")
  )
);

dao.findAll(page1);
```